# Jquery change hidden form field value

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this code but it isn't working on my localhost and I don't know why. Can anyone shed any light on this?

(Script is in head and the other code is in the body)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $(input[name='jsenabled']).val('1');

});
</script>



 <input type="hidden" name="jsenabled" value="0" />
    <label for="signup-email">Sign up for email offers, news &amp; events:</label>
    <input type="text" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" />
    <input type="submit" id="signup-button" value="Sign Me Up!" />
    <p id="signup-response"></p>
</fieldset>
```

EDITED
Weird thing is I have added this code to test if the value has been changed and it does fire up an alert, but firebug doesn't register the change.

```
$("input[name='jsenabled']").val("1");
    if($("input[name='jsenabled']").val = '1') {
    alert('frf');
    }
```

Comment: You can format source code with the `0101001` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 10):

1. jQuery selectors are strings: they must be quoted
2. jQuery.val() is a method, not a property. Don't forget the parenthesis.
3. The comparison operator is `==` not `=`.

You basically need to be more careful with your syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Try `$("input[name='jsenabled']").val('1');`  Pay attention at double quotes I added.

**edit** See more issues in Nick's and Alvaro's answers.

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around the selector, like this:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("input[name='jsenabled']").val('1'); 
});
```

Also when checking the value, use parenthesis, like this:

```
if($("input[name='jsenabled']").val() == '1') {
  alert('frf');
}
```

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a function, and called without any arguments *gets* the value.

On a more broad note, pay attention to the console, as Firebug should be throwing your JavaScript errors here for each of these, the console (which shows errors) is your best resource here.

Answer (score 1):

Can u try this  `$('input[name="jsenabled"]').val('1');`

Answer (score 0):

Álvaro is generally right, but even with the right syntax you wouldn't be able to change the value of hidden fields, though jQuery sees them as readonly, if I recognize right.

I'd met this problem for myself a few weeks ago, my solution was a normal input with the css class 'hidden'

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

afterwards, you could simply change the value of the hidden input field:

```
jQuery('#field_id.hidden').val('new_field_value');
```

Comment: Not sure how to word this nicely...this is completely incorrect information, you can change a hidden field with `.val()` like any other input.

Comment: Oh, I'm not offended at all. I've re-checked it and you're right, must have put it together with disabled input fields. 

Sry, next time I answer without hangover.

Comment: That's a wrong answer, you can change a hidden field and trigger onChange event

$("#hiddenId").val("new value").change();